# Pandas KeyError in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to select the country who has won the most Gold medals in the summer olympics using the following code.

```
def answer_one():
    most_gold = df["Gold"].max()
    country = df.loc[df['Gold'] == most_gold]
    return country.index[0]
answer_one()
```

Sometimes this works fine and gives me the correct output. However, if I restart the kernel without changing any of the code, sometimes it gives me a KeyError "Gold". How do I fix this inconsistency? (I have checked to make sure that 'Gold' is the correct key. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, it seems to be totally random)

Comment: Hey Emily, odds are this problem isn't random. Are you sure you're running your jupyter notebook in a linear fashion each time? What I mean by that is, are you defining your dataframe (namely your "gold" column) before you run this `answer_one()` function? Because this type of error is usually encountered when your dataframe or specific column hasn't been created yet.

Comment: I just checked, and while I was running it linearly I had some code between creating the 'gold' column and my desired code that changed the column name, creating the error. I fixed that code and resolved the issue. Thank You!

Comment: FYI, `idxmax()` will return the index of the max value